# Applying as a resident to another EU country with a still-valid EU resident permit? (Third party national)

Tags: visa, residency

I just finished my MA in Germany and have 6 months left on my jobseeker resident permit. I am a non-EU national from Southeast Asia.

Recently, I got a call from my old boss in Austria who wants to take me in as a business partner. I was then wondering if I can apply for a resident’s permit/self-employed visa in Austria while still being a German resident? Or does this mean that I have to go back to my home country and de-register from Germany completely to be able to do such an application?

The thing is I still have 6 months left as a German resident and of course there are risks of  getting denied the permit for my application to move to Austria - as such I still want to keep my options open as a jobseeker in Germany. Or to be able to apply for another EU country, I must de-register completely from my current residence?

Anyone been in a similar situation?

Comment: I don't see any reason why you can't apply from Germany. Have youaskedthe Austrian consulate?